# swing gui improving

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, look-and-feel

i am looking for some methods to improve swing gui for example i want to know about new components libraries , new methods to enhance swing performance , new methods to add special effect to swing gui and
new plaf for swing .

please i want to know how to use this topics and where to find some tutorials about it .

thanks.

Comment: Please use a capital letter from time to time. Preferably at the start of a sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for add ons to the Java Swing libraries, you can check out [SwingX](https://swingx.dev.java.net//)

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good book called Swing Hack, I strongly recommend. It will teach you a lot cool stuff to improve swing looking.

p.s. override paintComponent(Graphics g) always works and gives you new ideal :)

Answer (score 2):

How about [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/)?